What is the license for the SharePoint Framework (SPFx)?
I am working on a project that involves the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) for developing custom web parts and extensions.
I would like to understand the licensing terms for using SPFx. Specifically, I want to know what type of license governs the use of SPFx and any important details related to compliance.
Can anyone provide clarity or point me to the official documentation regarding the SPFx license? Thank you!

SharePoint Framework (SPFx) is an extensibility model for SharePoint and Microsoft 365 enabling developers to extend the Microsoft 365 services by including JavaScript driven components and experiences within the user interface.
If you have license to use SharePoint Online (like E1, E3, E5 or any other Microsoft 365 license with SharePoint), you can develop SPFx web parts & extensions and use them for free without any additional licenses.
Check these Microsoft documentations for more information:

SharePoint Framework license
Overview of the SharePoint Framework (SPFx)

Additional information:

What license do I need for SharePoint Framework
What is SPFx? – An extensibility model for Microsoft 365

